# Header("Location") en php no funciona

Tags: php, dominio

tengo un código php al principio de un documento, pero la función header no funciona. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
<?php
$lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);

function lang() {
    $lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
    switch ($lang) {
        case "es":
            return 'es';
            break;
        case "ca":
            return 'cat';
            break;
        case "en":
            return 'en';
            break;
        default:
            return 'en';
            break;
    }
}

if (!isset($_GET['lang'])) {
    header("Location: index.php?lang=" + lang()); ///// Aquí
}
else {
    if ($_GET['lang'] != "es" && $_GET['lang'] != "cat" && $_GET['lang'] != "en")
        header("Location: index.php?lang=" + lang()); ///// Aquí
    else echo $_GET['lang'];
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Gabinete</title>
<?php include_once("pred/meta.php"); ?>
</head>
<body>
<?php include_once("pred/header.php"); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿a qué te refieres con "no funciona"? ¿No hace nada?¿Redirecciona a un lugar incorrecto?

Comment: Hola, no hace nada, sigue en la misma página.

Comment: y no hay ningun error en tus logs?

Comment: intenta agregar esto al principio de tu código para ver si hay errores error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

Comment: He probado lo de los errores y no me dice nada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No he tenido oportunidad de probar tu código, pero por lo que veo, estás concatenando con `+` y en PHP se concatena con `.`

Comment: Vale gracias, lo habia pensado unos minutos antes, pero hasta mañana no puedo volver a programar. Mañana te digo si me ha funcionado.

Comment: Gracias, era eso

Answer (score 1):

Intenta esto:

```
$sLang = lang();
header("Location: index.php?lang=$sLang");
```

O si prefieres usa este (recomendado)

```
$sLang = lang();
echo "<script>location.href = 'index.php?lang=$sLang';</script>";
```